# Can gems be used by ruby code compiled with macrubyc

Tags: ruby, rubygems, llvm, macruby, macrubyc

MacRuby 0.5 includes a ruby compiler built on LLVM called macrubyc.

Does anyone know if it would be possible to dynamically load gems from compiled code? Or compile the gems and link them in? Is this planned? Or how compiled code will be able to make use of gems in general.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that as of MacRuby 0.6, something like this will compile

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'sequel'

DB = Sequel.mysql(...)
```

But fail at run time trying to load `mysql` leading me to think that it loads the gems at run time.